Vega via Deneb in Power BI sankey chart grouped source and target names
I d like to create a sankey chart chart using vega in Deneb. I found an article online and I have the following code, but I would like to show the countries grouped 
currently my result is like this, I could not add the gap correctly on both sides; 
here is my code..
https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/a6c6f4b41a20fd763d08ed519ba1fcda/Vega_Sankey_Chart_with_issue.json
can you please help me .
Thank you.

Have you seen the Sankey here: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase?tab=readme-ov-file#sankey-chart

@davidebacci Thank you, that is exactly what I needed. However, I have another question. I noticed that in the code, the data block contains "category" and "source." I created a table in Power BI with the same structure as the "source" part, but for the "category," I had to write it directly in the code. Is there a way to use a second table as a data source for the "category" in Power BI?
"data": [
{"name": "dataset"}, // this contains the value, source and destination from PBI table
{ "name": "categoryTable", "values": [ {"category": "A","stack":1,"sort": 1, ....}

Can you ask a second question with the details and mark this one as solved.

Vega sankey available here which can be used in Deneb and Power BI: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase?tab=readme-ov-file#sankey-chart

